# How can I make my icon <div>s show up next to each other, rather than underneath each other?

Tags: html, css

I have this

```
<a href="#"><div class="iconFriends"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="iconFavorite"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="iconPM"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="iconShield"></div></a>
```

and the css for the icons class looks all similiar to this:

```
.iconFriends{
background: url(../images/icons/friends_16x16.png) no-repeat;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
border: none;
}
```

Now the results is that there is like a `<br>` when I do this. But if i remove the div and make a normal `<img src="...">` It shows fine. How can i fix this?

Comment: As a side note:  Your HTML sample is invalid.  You cannot put a block element inside an inline element.  You should use a `span` tag for the icons instead of a `div`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

set your divs to have `display:inline-block` or better yet remove the divs and apply the styling to the `a` tags directly (*again with `display:inline-block`*)

**html**

```
<a href="#" class="iconFriends"></a>
<a href="#" class="iconFavorite"></a>
<a href="#" class="iconPM"></a>
<a href="#" class="iconShield"></a>
```

**css**

```
.iconFriends{
   background: url(../images/icons/friends_16x16.png) no-repeat;
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   border: none;

   display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The `inline-block` display mode is not uniformly supported, I think.

Comment: Or...  use `float:left;display:block;`

Comment: @Ioannis Karadimas:  That's a pervasive myth.

Comment: @Ioannis, if the receiving element is `inline` it should work even on IE6 according to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: @Stephen: I was under the impression that setting float:left; would automatically change the display type into block, do you know if that's true?

Comment: @Jasper, indeed. Setting `float:left` makes the element a block one.

Comment: @Jasper Uh...  That's a new one on me!  Looks like Ioannis and I both learned something.

Answer (score 1):

try giving them all a `float:left`

Comment: yeah - by default divs are all placed on new lines whereas images will keep going across until the parent element width is reached.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
.iconFriends{
 background: url(../images/icons/friends_16x16.png) no-repeat;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 border: none;
 float: left /* or right, depending on the desired outcome */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: replace the `<div>` with a `<span>`

Option 2: set the `<div>` to `display: inline;`. Its default `display` property value is `block`, which is why each one is on its own line.

```
.iconFriends {
    display: inline;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reversing the order of your elements, as such:

```
<div class="icon iconFriends"><a href="#"></a></div>
```

Note the extra `icon` class on the div.

Then use this for your CSS:

```
.icon a
{
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.iconFriends
{
    background: url(../images/icons/friends_16x16.png) no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Adding `float: left;` will put them all on the same line. Setting `display: block;` on the `a` will allow you to set the width and height (making the entire element clickable).